# Trouble accessing help documentation for a package I created

Tags: r, package

I'm new to R so I hope this isn't incredibly obvious. I created a package that contains two functions. I provided documentation using roxygen2 for each of the functions, documented and built the package as well as installed and restarted multiple times. I also pushed it up to github and have done everything I can think of to do, **yet I cannot access the help files that I created.** I always receive this error:

> No documentation for ‘myfunc’ in specified packages and libraries: you
>   could try ‘??myfunc’

Not only is ?myfunc not working, but when I attempt to install my own package to my own RStudio console, but I also receive this error:

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘yourpackage*’ is not
>   available (for R version 3.6.1)

What exactly is going wrong here, and how can I attempt to fix it? I've built packages before and this time I've followed all the same steps I've been taught to use and have used in the past, but for some reason, I'm being met with these errors. I would appreciate any and all help you all have to offer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What comes to mind is did you include `#\` @export` at the top of the function description. Can you link to your github page?

Comment: Another possibility - did you possibly build it with roxygen2 and devtools packages not up to date? Maybe try rebuilding after updating R and packages used to build or used in the package.

Comment: Yes! I did include #' @export at the top of both function descriptions.

Comment: I just updated roxygen2 and devtools and am facing the same errors as before

Comment: Could you link to your package's code(might be easier to "debug" that way) if possible?

Comment: Don't know your whole workflow there, but have you run `document()`? Having roxygen tags doesn't help unless `document()` is run

Comment: The code itself runs perfectly fine, so what would be most helpful for you to see?

Comment: @duckmayr I tried running document() but it couldn't find the function. I thought it was a part of the roxygen2 package, but I have that one installed and loaded, is it a part of a different package?

Comment: It's part of `devtools`

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much for your help!